# Nebular nb-option with ng-template

Tags: angular, nebular

Is there a way to place an icon inside a nb-option? I have readed the docs and can't find a way to do this. May be with ng-template?

Answer (score 0):

You can place image inside nb-option like below. Code also in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/e-select-default-value-yooqcp)=>
**HTML:**

```
 <nb-layout>
          <nb-layout-column>
            <nb-select [(selected)]="selectedOption">
              <nb-option *ngFor="let o of options" [value]="o">
               <div>
                    <img style="width:50px;height:50px" src="https://i.ibb.co/sm8s569/2.jpg" alt="2" border="0">
                   {{ o.name }}
                </div>
              </nb-option>
            </nb-select>
    
          </nb-layout-column>
        </nb-layout>
```

**TS:**

```
export class AppComponent  {
  options = [
    { value: 1, name: '1' },
    { value: 2, name: '2' },
    { value: 3, name: '3' },
  ];

  selectedOption;

  constructor() {
    this.selectedOption = this.options[1];
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It worked fine with an img tag. Did not worked for me with an nbicon instead, neither with a fontawsome icon. <nb-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions$ | async" [value]="option">
              {{ option }} <nb-icon [options]="{animation:{type: 'zoom'}}" nbTooltip="Eliminar tarea" nbTooltipIcon="trash-2-outline" nbTooltipStatus="danger"></nb-icon>
            </nb-option>